# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Flutter install

Tags: flutter

I was installing flutter and the error showing is

`Could not find or load main class`
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`
I have already downloaded SDK manager

Comment: have you downloaded the android sdk and set it's path

Comment: Hello, are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: thank you for replying solved it by just removing space in name